# Getting the wrong output with SQL query don't understand why

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this table called Activity, and I want to find the fraction of users that login on consecutive days. The data shows everytime a user with user_id logs in from device with device_id and how many games they played on that date.

| player_id | device_id | log_in_date | games_played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-01-11 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-01-12 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2017-06-25 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2016-03-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 2018-07-03 | 6 |

So from this data only player with player_id 1 has logged in on consecutive days, so the output should be 1/3 (0.33).

This is the query I used, I can't find any errors in the syntax or logic but it gives me an output of 0. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(SUM(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(a.first_log_in, a.last_log_in) = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) / COUNT(a.player_id), 2) AS fraction
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      player_id,
      MIN(log_in_date) AS first_log_in,
      MAX(log_in_date) AS last_log_in
    FROM Activity
    GROUP BY player_id) a
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Using MySQL 8.0

Comment: You have your parameters in the datediff function in the wrong order, try to put first the last log in

Comment: Besides that, the logic is wrong, what woukd happen if user 1 had another log in in 2016-01-13??

Comment: in mysql must the older day come first to get a positive value see https://dbfiddle.uk/shzzJ0K9

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). In particular, [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) can be used to calculate the difference with previous date:

```
SELECT activity.*,
    DATEDIFF(
        log_in_date,
        LAG(log_in_date) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY log_in_date)
    ) AS days
FROM activity;
```

| player_id | device_id | log_in_date | games_played | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-01-11 | 4 | (NULL) |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-01-12 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2017-06-25 | 2 | (NULL) |
| 3 | 1 | 2016-03-02 | 1 | (NULL) |
| 3 | 4 | 2018-07-03 | 6 | 853 |
| 4 | 99 | 2016-01-01 | 5 | (NULL) |
| 4 | 99 | 2017-08-09 | 8 | 586 |
| 4 | 99 | 2017-08-10 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 99 | 2017-08-11 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 105 | 2018-09-10 | 1 | (NULL) |
| 5 | 105 | 2018-09-12 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 105 | 2018-09-15 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 105 | 2018-09-15 | 1 | 0 |

Once you have that, you can calculate the percentage with good old [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count), using [CASE ... END](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) to filter out unwanted values and `DISTINCT` to discard duplicates:

```
WITH activity_days AS (
    SELECT activity.*, DATEDIFF(log_in_date, LAG(log_in_date) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY log_in_date)) AS days
    FROM activity
)
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT player_id) AS total_players,
    COUNT(DISTINCT case days when 1 then player_id end) AS consecutive_day_players,
    COUNT(DISTINCT case days when 1 then player_id END) / COUNT(DISTINCT player_id) AS ratio
FROM activity_days;
```

| total_players | consecutive_day_players | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 0,4000 |

I added some more rows to data set, you can see them in the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/G3eENoCL).